# How to add a Jetty QoS Filter in a Spring environment with programmatic configuration

Tags: spring, configuration, filter, jetty

I want to add the Quality of Service filter in our Spring/Jetty webapp.  I can find no documentation on how to *programmatically* configure a filter. Can someone provide an example or link, if such documentation exists?  Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need a Servlet 3.0+ container and you should forget about web.xml altogether. You need to extend a `WebApplicationInitializer`. You could also extend `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` which brings convenient methods to do that:

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    return new Filter[] {
      new QualityServiceFilter()
    };
  }

}
```

See the [Spring reference documentation "Code-based Servlet container initialization"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-container-config).